# E_LoadingConf Roxy Fileman Custom Integration with MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roxy-fileman

Using an MVC Area I am using Roxy Fileman for file upload functionality.  I am trying to use a custom integration when I do I get the error "E_LoadingConf".  I verified my conf.json file is correct and the problem seems to be in routing, when I check developer tools I see a 404 for conf.json it seems it is sending it through my default route for the area /Admin/MediaAdmin/conf.json.  It is not honoring the location of the file /scripts/admin/fileman/conf.json.  I tried adding an ignore in my area registration and then my global registration

```
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{*confJson}", new { confJson = @".*\conf.json(/.*)?" });
```

But this does not seem to help at all.  Any idea how to force the area to honor the actual physical route to the file?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add the MIMETYPE .json to your web.config or IIS mime setting, and check again.
http://www.roxyfileman.com/FAQ

Comment: Actually the mime-type is already added, it seems to be the fact that fileman relies on relative pathing. since the area is routed using MVC, it takes it to the parent of the file it is called from not from the relative path of the application.  I began modifying the source to take an overload for the base path, but it is in technical debt for the time being, I will post the solution once I finish it.